# Flexbox makes horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a shopping mall site with flexbox layout, but flexbox causes problems in certain areas.

Flexbox seems to make horizontal scrolling in certain areas, but I don't want that.

Comment: Your question is very unclear so please make it more understandable, and maybe add some drawing to show how it should look like. Also, you have a lot of syntax errors, like _blank space_ in property names, classes and values/value units.

Comment: @LGSon can you watch my site? [basic links](http://www.dittomall.com). just my problem is that some mark up make horizontal scroling. but i don't solve this problem

Comment: No, we in general doesn't parse an entire site, web companies does that, but I can say that your banner holds 3 images, not 1 as in your above code sample, and they together is 1920px wide, while your site is 1116px wide. That is one reason you get horizontal scroll.

Comment: Do you want your banner to be fully visible?

Comment: The problem is **not** with firefox but with your understanding of how web pages are/should render... if you correct your understanding and learn CSS, you would fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the images in your banner are too wide to fit in most viewports, so they force the page to be wider.

There is no easy way to correct this purely with CSS without either causing the images to overlap each other or warping the images' aspect ratio.

This CSS will fix the horizontal scrolling, but it will squish the first and last images:

```
.dittomall-banner img {
  width: 33%;
}
```

To truly fix things so that your images can maintain their original aspect ratio and also not cause the page to be too wide, you should edit the images so that they are cropped tightly, then use a `background-color` on `.dittomall-banner` that's the same as the background color in the first and third images. Then, center the images within the banner.

Assuming you crop the images so they are all equally sized (e.g., 300px x 100px), your final HTML and CSS could look like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="dittomall-banner">
  <div class="banner-inner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.dittomall.com/theme/dittomall/img/banner1.png" alt="banner1">
    <img src="http://www.dittomall.com/theme/dittomall/img/banner2.png" alt="banner2">
    <img src="http://www.dittomall.com/theme/dittomall/img/banner3.png" alt="banner3">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dittomall-banner {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ed8c7b;
}
.banner-inner-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want your banner size to change according to your screen size. Please replace your CSS with the below code:

```
    html,body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    body {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 100 vh;
        align-items:center;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    header {
        flex: 1 100 %;
    }
    .dittomall-banner {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 100%;
    }
    img {
        width:100%;
    }
```

Hope this will help!